# php5 fpm: how do you generate core dump from segfault?

Tags: php, php5, php-fpm

Under load, my PHP5-fpm (on 32bit ubuntu 10.10) produces segfaults like the following:

```
kernel: [4881937.884863] php5-fpm[2638]: segfault at 4204eb41 ip 0832d235 sp bfcea5e0 error 4 in php5-fpm[8048000+70d000]
```

How do I make it so these segfaults produce a core dump so that I can inspect the call stack to figure out where the segfault is coming from?

Where do the core dumps go once they are produced?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can enable core dump with:

```
su -
echo '/tmp/core-%e.%p' > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/core_uses_pid
ulimit -c unlimited
```

Set the `rlimit_core` directive in `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` to unlimited:

```
rlimit_core = unlimited
```

Comment: I just found the answer here:
https://bugs.php.net/bugs-generating-backtrace.php